# Replace multiple instances of text surrounded by specific characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

How do I replace all instances where I have #sometext# in order of the array provided?

The text is a string and my goal is to search for all instances where I have some text surrounded by the "#" character. Then replace those instances with values in the array in the order of the array

Example:

```js
const text = "You are the #RANKED# highest ranked user (out of #TOTALUSER# people)"

const myArray = [10, 50];
```

After searching and replacing the text should be:

```
"You are the 10 highest ranked user (out of 50 people)"
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/610406/8967612

Comment: You can use `const result = text.replace(/#([^#]+)#/g, _ => myArray.shift());`, you can clone `myArray` beforehand if you don't want to modify the original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text.replace(/#([^#]+)#/g, _ => myArray.shift());
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The text is a string and my goal is to search for all instances where I have some text surrounded by # character. Then replace those instances with values in the array in the order of the array.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't read your question carefully. Thanks for the other comment, I got the idea. You may study [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).